# Unable to find file "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php"

Tags: php, symfony

When I run

```
php app/console server:run
```

I receive the following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]  Unable to find file
>   "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php".

**Version Info:**

> symfony 2.7
>
> php 7.3

Answer (score 0):

Check whether are you in the root directory of your project.